# Div element automagically larger than specified?

Tags: html, css, size

No matter how hard I try to make this `div` 40px tall, it's `height` keeps getting larger.

Here is sample HTML:

```css
div {
  /* To prove the div does get larger */
  display: table;
  background-color: red;
  /* Not even explicitly setting height to 40px helps: */
  height: 40px;
  max-height: 40px;
  /* Ofc, problem occurs also without these two lines. */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x40">
</div>
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x40">
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x0cky89k/1/)

I hope that the intend is clear: the `div` should only be as large as the image inside it.

Since the image inside is `40px` tall, I'd expect the `div` to be `40px` tall as well.

However, it isn't. It keeps getting larger. I've set `background-color` to red to show the problem prominently:

[image]

Yeah, the above is exactly what Firefox shows me. I've also tried IE 11, with same results.

I tried looking at Firefox inspector. It seems that for some reason Firefox sets the `div`'s height to `44.5px`.

Why does this occur? How to stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because `img` is a inline element therefore creates space, you must set `img` to display as a block level, and you won't need anything else in the `div`

```css
div {
  display: table;
  background: red
}
img {
  display: block 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x40">
</div>
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x40">
```

**UPDATE** from comments,

> The problem is that i kinda need two images in this div, one next to
>   each other.

use `inline-block` instead.

```css
div {
  display: table;
  background: red;
  font-size: 0 /* updated from comments */
}
img {
  display: inline-block /* updated from comments */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/175x40">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/175x40">
</div>
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x40">
```

Comment: Would setting `line-height: 0;` in the div be a reasonable approach?

Comment: if you had some text inside that `div` then no. that's why I gave you this option, because it only "touch" the element which needs to be "touched"

Comment: The problem is that i kinda need two images in this div, one next to each other... I've put only one image in the sample because, well, it was an (over)simplified sample only. Setting the display to `block` will cause these two images to be in a row, which is not appropriate...

Comment: then use `inline-block` which is also a block level, see updated answer

Comment: `inline-block` means inline-level, block container. i.e. it is inline level, not block level.

Comment: @Alohci you totally right, its past midnight here, sleepy and and stuff :)